# How to bind radio button values to the formcontrolname when changed in angular8 using reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi i am using reactive forms to bind the values to the radio buttons. Now the values have got binded, but if i change value from `yes to no` it is not getting updated in the formcontrol neither in the array of objects i have used. Can anyone help me how can this be solved, here i used reactive forms mainly because if there is any change in the toggle buttons then the application can be saved or i need to show message saying no changes to save, so i have used reactive forms and i am struck with this. Can anyone help me to solve this.

TS:

```
this.musicForm = this.fb.group({
      musicPreferences: this.fb.array(this.musicPreferences.map(x => this.fb.control(x.boolValue))),
    });
    this.musicForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
          this.formEdit = true;
          console.log('agentSettingsInfoForm', this.formEdit)
        })
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slh2ol?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
 <div class="col pt-lg-4">
            <label for="" class="font-weight-bold">Agency Policy</label>
            <div class="row" formArrayName="musicPreferences">
              <div class="col columns-2">
                <div class="d-flex mb-3 w-100 justify-content-between align-items-center" *ngFor="let toggleValue of musicPreferences;let i = index">
                <label  for="{{toggleValue.id}}">{{toggleValue.label}}</label>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" [class.active]="!toggleValue.boolValue" (click)="onItemChange(false,toggleValue.id)">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" id="{{toggleValue.id}}"  [attr.checked]="toggleValue.boolValue"  [disabled]="isReadOnly" > No
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary " [class.active]="toggleValue.boolValue" (click)="onItemChange(true,toggleValue.id)">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" id="{{toggleValue.id}}" [attr.checked]="toggleValue.boolValue"  [disabled]="isReadOnly" > Yes
                  </label>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

or using this demo, is it possible to make checkbox like Yes and No button, using css can this demo be made like above one.
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkvzgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You have two `id` on both input

Comment: ya sorry i corrected it, how can this be solved?